# How to modify or add more dictionary tabs in Cambridge dictionary fast app?

Tags: applications, editing

[image: Cambridge dictionary fast app]

As you can see in the picture, this [Cambridge dictionary app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=vn.vietbill.cambridge) has some dictionary tabs, such as: Cambridge, Oxford. Those dictionary tabs have a link of their website. How can I add more dictionary tabs like collins, merriam dictionary?

Comment: May be you should simply contact the author and ask to add this feature?

Comment: @robert They might not take any action in this regard.

Comment: Unless the sites & parameters are not hardcoded but stored/configured somewhere else instead, I'm not sure it's possible for us to change anything. Reverse-engineering an app and doing some coding is outside of the scope of this site though.

Comment: How can I know the sites & parameters are not hardcoded? Is there any way to find it?

Comment: Hello Rajib. Please don't vandalize your post by editing it and making it incomprehensible.

Answer (score 2):

I downloaded the APK file and loaded it into Jadx.

The dictionary tabs and their target are hard coded in the APK DEX byte code (it is a large switch case code entry in the MainActivity that sets the target url of each of the 6 tabs).
Therefore modification requires decompiling and recompiling skills - however such actions are out of scope of this site.

Therefore the only answer we can give to you is to contact the author of the app and ask if other dictionary sites can be added.

Comment: I can decompile this app . Please tell me what files should I modify? Please robert

Comment: @Rajib Sorry but I can and will not help you on that topic. Decompiling does not necessarily means you are able to recompile the app. The highest chance of decompiling and recompiling is using `apktool` however it decompiles not Java but Smali code and modifying smali code is a tough task and usually requires good programming skills.